# AdMob Android integration - what permissions to ask for?

Tags: java, android, permissions, ads, admob

In the various videos on the AdMob integration, I've seen that only permission to access the internet is asked for:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Not that I am an expert in advertising, but wouldn't AdMob need the user's geographic location as well, so that they can serve location specific ads?  Or avoid serving certain ads based on a location, like maybe not offering me a Big Mac if I am in India or not adverting a ham sandwich if I am in an Arab country?

If AdMob needs those permissions, how do I ask for them?

Comment: I have no clue, but your question was the first of the real new year in EST.  enjoy it! :-)

Comment: @pjammer Surely, Jeff and Joel have some kind of prize reserved for me.  Also, I lead a sad life.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though you might be partially correct we cannot rule out the possibility of retrieving the current location from your Internet connection. Many websites do that. AdMob severs could also be doing the same thing since you cannot expect all android devices to have a GPS hardware in it. Though network providers value cannot match the accuracy of GPS in most cases it can find out the location(state//city) you are in quite easily i believe

http://www.admob.com/docs/AdMob_Android_SDK_Instructions.pdf

Check this pdf out Page 4. Probably this is what you are asking for?

```
AdManager.setAllowUseOfLocation
```

You need to add relevant permissions in you manifest which is also mentioned in that document

Answer (score 0):

The permission you need to add is ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION.